# Hibernate JPA: JoinTable with distinctive column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Let's consider model like this:

```
Author
+ List<Books> popularBooks;
+ List<Books> unknownBooks;

Book
+ String name;
```

Can I define a @JoinTable to use distinctive column for both `popularBooks` and `unknownBooks` so that I can use distinctive column instead of two tables? For instance table like this:

```
author_to_book
+ author_id
+ book_id
+ is_popular
```

What I would like to achieve is that once I put a book into `popularBooks`, Hibernate would set the `is_popular` to true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually by setting the isPopular field to `true` when you add a `Book` to the `popularBooks` list. For example:

Create a field called `isPopular` in your `Book` entity.

public class Book{
 ...
 boolean isPopular;
}

Create methods say `addPopularBook(Book book)` and `addUnknownBook(Book book)` in your `Author` entity like this:

```
public void addPopularBook(Book book){
 book.isPopular(true);
 this.popularBooks.add(book);
}

public void addUnknownBook(Book book){
 book.isPopular(false); // This field is false by default, so no need to add this line.
 this.unknownBooks.add(book);
}
```

Now when you add books to `Author` then call these methods, so that all the Books inside `popularBooks` will have property `isPopular` set to `true` where as all `unknownBooks` will have `isPopular` set to `false`.

**Update:**

Based on comments I understand that you need a many-to-many relationship and the join table should have the extra column called isPopular, you can follow this link to understand how you can achieve that.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: Okay, my bad, in fact I wanted to have m:n relationship, so one book can belong to several authors, but does not have to be popular for all of them. That mean, the book can't have the field "popular" as I stated in the schema.

Comment: so you have many-to-many relationship with JOIN table. A Book is an entity and it can be popular or unknown at a time, so this property should go into the `Book` table itself. Do you want to maintain the popularity in JOIN table? then in that case you have to add a new column for JOIN table and there again you have to do it manually saying what value you want to set for this property. In either case, you have to do it manually itself.

Comment: Yes, I want to have it in the join table exactly as I have shown in the schema. I want to know, whether Hibernate is able to handle this column exactly as it is able to handle @OrderBy column.

Comment: you can add the extra column in join table. By the way `@OrderBy` is just for ordering the results based on some column, it has no relation in this particular context.

Comment: Well I have it, but I don't know how to access it with the @JoinTable.

Comment: @Vojtěch, please check this link to know how to create extra fields in join table - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/